# "Unable to find an entry point" exception when trying to import a native DLL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++, dll

I wanted to use a native Dll in my C# .net application as this:

```
public const int WFSDDESCRIPTION_LEN = 256;
public const int WFSDSYSSTATUS_LEN = 256;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct LPWFSVERSION
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 4)]
   int WVersion;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 4)]
   int WLowVersion;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 4)]
   uint WHighVerion;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = WFSDDESCRIPTION_LEN + 1)]
   public string szDescription;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = WFSDSYSSTATUS_LEN + 1)]
   public string szSystemStatus;
 }        
[DllImport("MSXFS.DLL", EntryPoint = "WFSStartUP", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = false)]
public static extern int WFSStartUP([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]int dwVersionsRequired, ref LPWFSVERSION ver);
```

and here the code where I've used the imported function:

```
        LPWFSVERSION Ver = new LPWFSVERSION();
        WFSStartUP(0x31, ref Ver);
```

the problem is that it throws an exception which says:"Unable to find an entry point"

I have dump the msxfs.dll with dumpbin and the result was this:

```
Section contains the following exports for MSXFS.d
00000000 characteristics
46938FBD time date stamp Tue Jul 10 17:25:09 200
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
      37 number of functions
      37 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00009310 WFMAllocateBuffer
      2    1 000093D0 WFMAllocateMore
       .
       .
     32   1F 00005BD0 WFSOpen
     33   20 00007C80 WFSRegister
     34   21 00008CD0 WFSSetBlockingHook
     35   22 00004FA0 WFSStartUp
```

It seems to be there was no problem in dll side as the dumpbin could find entry point as well. I don't know what the problem is? :(

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with your dll?

Comment: And does it show `WFSStartUP` anywhere? I can't see that in the dump...

Comment: Sorry Jon, it was left on copy/past. i modified it.

Comment: @Hans you can post it as answer to let me mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
>  35   22 00004FA0 WFSStartUp
> ```

That's Up, not UP.